# Json to jsquery to html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Помогите выполнить задачу в перемещении всего содержимого страницы в отдельную базу данных JSON. База JSON должна быть загружена с использованием сценария, написанного с использованием Jquery. Сценарий должен быть помещен в отдельный JS-файл и загружен в HTML-файл. Ткните пальцем, где изучить как это зделать. На паре смог только переписать что препод делал, а так ничего не получаеться. Может где-то ошибку допустил........

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму, что ты имеешь в виду под "база JSON". 
JSON ('JavaScript Object Notation') -- это формат записи данных, а никакая не база. 
Например:

```
{
   "my_languages": ["JavaScript", "Java", "PHP", "C#"]
}
```

Подробнее про [JSON](https://learn.javascript.ru/json)

Т.е., скорее всего, тебе нужно просто получить json-объект из данных клиента.

Далее, по заданию:

1. jQuery (далее - JQ) -- это библиотека JavaScript, как ты, наверняка уже загуглил
2. Инструкция о подключении JQ: [Подключение JQ](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_jQuery#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.B3.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B7.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_jQuery)
3. Собственно, аналогичным образом подключается и любой другой js-файл. Поэтому создавай новый текстовый документ, меняй его расширение на .js, прописывай к нему `<script src="относительный/путь/от/страницы/до/скрипта.js"></script>` в самой html-странице. **C этим файлом и будешь работать.** Только помни, что скрипт должен быть размещен в конце страницы перед `... </body>`, чтоб на момент его выполнения элементы уже отрендерились.
4. Затем тебе нужно собственно создать [объект](https://learn.javascript.ru/object) и собрать в него данные из **DOM-узлов** страницы. В максимально упрощенном виде, DOM-узлы - это элементы ([теги](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/html/lesson3.php)) страницы, которые ты видишь в окне броузера:
   самый простой способ выбрать тег на странице - использовать [функцию JQ](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B). Для этого нужно просто поместить [селектор](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/42) в обертку **$("*селектор*")**.
   Например, чтоб получить содержание твоего вопроса, открой консоль броузера (F12) -> вкладка 'console' (консоль) -> введи `$('.post-text p').text()`. Подробнее о методе [.text()](https://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=31). Тоже самое пишешь и в своем скрипте.js
5. Возвращаемые значения из функции `.text()` - записываешь в объект (см. начало четвертого пункта).
6. Далее переводишь объект в JSON-формат (это описано в самой первой ссылке про json).

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос совершенно не ясен, однако эта ссылка должна помочь
https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Одно могу сказать, очень круто что теперь на парах учат джаваскрипт. Нас мучали паскакалем.

Comment: В итоге советую забить на препода и всё сделать на связке реакт+вебпак

Comment: без знания языка, к сожалению, вряд ли получится изучить react. Да и jq -- имхо, хоть и прошлый век, но знать его должен любой frontend-developer, тем более начинающий. Но да, хоть я и не учился в универе, но прогресс дошел и до советских вузов, это хоть что-то ... хотя лучше бы дали материал по vanila.js.